# Adding minus (-) when menu is expanded and plus (+) when contracted

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to toggle **-** and **+** when menu is expanded and contracted. I have the choice of adding and removing classes with an image as background but I decided to do it with the **-** and **+** as html.
The approach I'm taking is `.remove()` the `<span class="plus">` and `.append()` with `<span class="minus">` but I'm stuck there. **[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/22ZyM/)**. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you're using a fixed-width font for the plus and minus characters, so that the rest of the line will line up consistently.

Comment: I tried width:10px; height:10px; font-size:100%; and I don't see any improvement. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: By fixed-width, I mean a monospace font like Courier New, so the width of the `+` character is the same as the `-` character. In a lot of variable-width fonts, the widths are different, so they would be off by a few pixels.

Comment: Learned something new.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#vertical-menu ul ul").slideUp();
    $('.plus',this).html('+');
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
        $('.plus').html('+');
        $('.plus',this).html('-');
    }
})
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22ZyM/3/)

Comment: Hi Sachin! I added another level to the menu but what is happening now is that when I open a sub-menu the parent change the - to +, parents should keep the - while the children are expanded right? Take a look in the menu to 2013 to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/22ZyM/5/. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.navbar .dropdown-item').on('click', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle');
    var $parent = $el.offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
    $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');

    if (!$parent.parent().hasClass('navbar-nav')) {
        if ($parent.hasClass('show')) {
            $parent.removeClass('show');
            $el.next().removeClass('show');
            $el.next().css({"top": -999, "left": -999});
        } else {
            $parent.parent().find('.show').removeClass('show');
            $parent.addClass('show');
            $el.next().addClass('show');
            $el.next().css({"top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4});
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});

$('.navbar .dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).find('li.dropdown').removeClass('show open');
    $(this).find('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show open');
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working sample (dont close all the slides, for this I suggest you the accordion feature of Jquery UI)

```
$("#vertical-menu h3").click(function () {
    //Inner 
    var jqInner = $(this).next();
    if (jqInner.is(":visible"))
    {
        jqInner.slideUp()
        $(this).find('span').html('-');
    }
    else
    {
        jqInner.slideDown()
        $(this).find('span').html('+');
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/22ZyM/4/