# How to create custom accordion with jquery by expand and collapse parents and child with delegate

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some ul li tag with parents and child class,I need to make it accordion like if I click states all the child of states should be expand again when I click capital all the child of capitals should be expand and all the child of states should be collapse.I tried already but its not working individually,Can anyone please help me,It needs to be make with delegate method only.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".childs").hide();
  
  $(".collapse").delegate(".parents", "click", function(){
    $(".childs").show(); 
  });  
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style-type:none;}
.parents{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse">
  <ul>
    <li class="parents">States</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>states 1</a></li>
        <li><a>states 2</a></li>
        <li><a>states 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parents">Capitals</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>Capital 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "It needs to be make with delegate method only" it sound like a homework. This site is not for that. And I not recommand use "delegate" because its deprecated in 3+.

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this use es6 instead it is way faster and less bug prone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You might know .delegate() has been deprecated in jQuery 3.0.**

Instead of `$(".childs").show()` use `$(".childs").hide();` and `$(this).next().find(".childs").show();` lines. That will fix your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".childs").hide();
 $(".collapse").delegate(".parents", "click", function(){
    if($(this).next().find(".childs").is(":hidden")){
     $(".parents").not(this).find(".collapseExpand").removeClass("minus").addClass("plus");
     $(".childs").hide();
   $(this).next().find(".childs").show();
    }else{
   $(this).next().find(".childs").hide();
    }
    $(this).find(".collapseExpand").toggleClass("plus, minus");
});  
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style-type:none;}
.parents{cursor:pointer;}
.plus::before{
content:"+";
}
.minus::before{
content:"-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse">
  <ul>
    <li class="parents"><span class="plus collapseExpand"></span> States</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>states 1</a></li>
        <li><a>states 2</a></li>
        <li><a>states 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parents"><span class="plus collapseExpand"></span> Capitals</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>Capital 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can test it here as well.. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/zys3t6ck/1/

**Update 1 :**
Added plus (+) minus (-) symbols.

**Update 2:**
Added close functionality on opened element click.

https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/zys3t6ck/4/

Comment: Thanks for your help,I need one more help to add plus and minus symbol  when expand and collapse

Comment: Here you go.! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453980/adding-minus-when-menu-is-expanded-and-plus-when-contracted

Comment: I have updated the answer above.. You can also test it here. https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/zys3t6ck/1/

Comment: Here if I click on parents corresponding childs are not hiding.only its hiding ,if I click on next parents

Comment: I have updated the answer. :) https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/zys3t6ck/4

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are the .delegate() solution (deprecated in jQuery 3.0) and .on() solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".childs").hide();
  
  // Use .delegate()
  $(".collapse").delegate(".parents", "click", function(){
      $(".childs").hide();
      $(this).next().children(".childs").show(); 
  });


  /*
  // Use .on(). Recommended method because .delegate() is deprecated in jQuery 3.0
 $(".collapse").on("click", ".parents", function(){
     $(".childs").hide();
     $(this).next().children(".childs").show();  
 });
 */

    
});
```

```css
ul li{list-style-type:none;}
.parents{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapse">
  <ul>
    <li class="parents">States</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>states 1</a></li>
        <li><a>states 2</a></li>
        <li><a>states 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parents">Capitals</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>Capital 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whithout jQuery it could look like the following:

```js
const parents = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.parents' ) );
const childs = Array.from( document.querySelectorAll( '.childs' ) );

parents.forEach( ( parent, i ) => {
  parent.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    childs[i].classList.toggle( 'active' )
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.parents {
  cursor:pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.childs {
  display: none;
}

.childs.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse">
  <ul>
    <li class="parents">States</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>states 1</a></li>
        <li><a>states 2</a></li>
        <li><a>states 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parents">Capitals</li>
    <li>
      <ul class="childs">
        <li><a>Capital 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Capital 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```